# Copying files from one directory to another in java throws NoSuchFileException

Tags: java

I have a HashSet of Strings, which are names of files that I want to copy from the working direcorory to the "path" directory. I find that the following piece of code should be working, however, I get a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /commits/1/hello.txt` exception.

```
  Hashset<String> stagedQueue = HashSet<String>();
    stagedQueue.put("hello.txt");
    stagedQueue.put("bye.txt");


String path = "/commits/" + commitID;

                for (String file : stagedQueue) {
                    Files.copy((new File(file).toPath()), 
                        (new File(path + "/" + file).toPath()));
```

What can I do to fix this? I can't figure out why I am getting these exceptions. Please note that I am moving these into an empty directory.

Comment: Is that a relative or absolute path by intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't go through `File`; you use java.nio.file.

Your problem here is that you try and copy your initial file into a directory which does not exist yet:

```
String path = "/commits/" + commitID;
```

First of all, this is the destination directory, so call it `dstdir`, for instance. Then create the base directory and copy the files into it:

```
final Path basedir = Paths.get("/commits", commitId);

Files.createDirectories(basedir);

for (final String file: baseQueue)
    Files.copy(Paths.get(file), basedir.resolve(file));
```